# Is there a way to skip a recurring notification using flutter_local_notifications?

Tags: flutter, notifications

I'm using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to schedule **daily reminder notifications** but I want to prevent users from being bothered by the notification if they already accomplished the action that day. In other words, I want to be able to skip a day.

Since there is no way with `FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin` to run some code before triggering each recurring notification, I thought I could do the following workaround when needing to skip one day: cancel the recurring notification and **reschedule it with a `TZDateTime` parameter set to the next day**. Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way.

The doc clearly says ([source](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart#L273-L279)):

> Note that when a value is given, the [scheduledDate] may not represent the first time the notification will be shown. An example would be if the date and time is currently 2020-10-19 11:00 (i.e. 19th October 2020 11:00AM) and [scheduledDate] is 2020-10-21 10:00 and the value of the [matchDateTimeComponents] is [DateTimeComponents.time], then the next time a notification will appear is 2020-10-20 10:00.

I'm afraid the only solution at this point is to manage my own background tasks using something like [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) instead of `FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin`. Am I right? Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you find any? I also want to trigger periodic notification but in the specified timeframe.  Please help if you've found anything.

Comment: @akshaybhange Unfortunately it seems like the way to accomplish this now is by following what I'm describing, using something like workmanager.

Comment: what about iOS. Need something for that too.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem. The solution I'm going with is manually scheduling all the periodic notifications for X time into the future (say one month) with [zonedSchedule](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin/zonedSchedule.html) (not configuring it to repeat).

Next, you can cancel any of the notifications you want with [cancel](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin/cancel.html). Then, you just have to make sure to reschedule a month into the future of daily notifications when it gets close to the initial scheduling time. You can use [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to keep track of the limit of the scheduling to check whenever the app is opened for example.

Comment: I like this idea. It wouldn't even need to be for a month. A week would probably be enough. If the user ignores the notifications for a week without opening the app, they probably don't want the notifications anyway.