# Pause notification in flutter local notifications plugin?

Tags: flutter, notifications

How do I go about pausing a notification? I am aware of the ability to cancel a notification, but what about pausing them? Should I cancel on pause and then create a new one on resume?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730762/is-there-a-way-to-skip-a-recurring-notification-using-flutter-local-notification